# Error when trying to load dl format using igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to load the [kapferer min dataset](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/ucinet/kapmine.dat) into r using the igraph function "read_graph"

The code is very simple, however it throws an error.

```
test_g <-read_graph("http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/ucinet/kapmine.dat", format = "dl")
```

> Error in read.graph.dl(file, ...) :    At foreign.c:3050 : syntax
>   error, unexpected $end, expecting DL in line 1, Parse error

The as can be seen by following the link the file does begin with DL. The only clue I can find to this is a [message from 2015](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2015-01/msg00047.html) which basically says file a bug report.

Can dl files not beloaded by igraph at the moment, or is there some trick to it?

Comment: The documentation (https://igraph.org/r/doc/read_graph.html) does say that "Right now as_edgelist, pajek, graphml, gml, ncol, lgl, dimacs and graphdb are supported" - so not dl

Comment: Fair enough,The old first part of documentation says one thing the rest says something else trick. I should have read it all.

Comment: The not mentioning of DL seems to be an error in the documentation, as `read.graph.dl` is implemented. The functionality to read DL files is just rudimentary as the [comment](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2015-01/msg00047.html) says.

Comment: I guess because, there wasn't a clear standard the loader is a bit hit and miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there doesn't seem to be a clear way to load dl files I have made a loader that seems to work well for dl graph on the [Pajek website](http://vlado.fmf.uni-lj.si/pub/networks/data/). The function is a bit scrappy and has not been extensively tested, but it may be useful to some who want to use certain graphs that are not available in a more common format. If there is more to date information on these datasets, then this code can be ignored.

```
load_dl_graph <- function(file_path, directed){

  raw_mat <- readLines(file_path) %>%
  enframe()

row_labels_row <- grep( "ROW LABELS:", raw_mat$value)
column_labels_row <- grep( "COLUMN LABELS:", raw_mat$value)
level_labels_row <- grep("LEVEL LABELS:",raw_mat$value )
data_table_row <- grep( "DATA:", raw_mat$value)


row_labels <- raw_mat %>%
  slice((row_labels_row+1):(column_labels_row-1)) %>%
  select(from = value)

column_labels <- raw_mat %>%
  slice((column_labels_row+1):(level_labels_row-1)) %>% pull(value)

table_levels <- raw_mat %>%
  slice((level_labels_row+1):(data_table_row+-1)) %>% pull(value)

data_df <- raw_mat %>%
  slice((data_table_row+1):nrow(.)) %>%
  select(value) %>%
  mutate(value = str_squish(value)) %>%
  separate(col = value, into = column_labels, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(table_id = rep(1:length(table_levels), each = nrow(.)/length(table_levels)))

tables_list <- 1:length(table_levels) %>%
  map(~{

    data_df %>%
      filter(table_id ==.x) %>%
      select(-table_id) %>%
      bind_cols(row_labels,.) %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = 2:ncol(.), names_to = "to", values_to = "values") %>%
      filter(values ==1) %>%
      select(-values) %>%
      graph_from_data_frame(., directed = directed)

  })

names(tables_list) <- table_levels

return(tables_list)

}
```